Isar caused Error: The integer literal 6284318083599466921 can't be represented exactly in JavaScript
I failed to get isar database running. I have the following code:
import 'package:isar/isar.dart';

part 'note.g.dart';

@Collection()
class Note {
  Id id = Isar.autoIncrement;
  late String text;
}

Next, I ran:
$ dart run build_runner build
Building package executable... (9.0s)
Built build_runner:build_runner.
[INFO] Generating build script completed, took 508ms
[INFO] Precompiling build script... completed, took 6.6s
[INFO] Building new asset graph completed, took 1.7s
[INFO] Checking for unexpected pre-existing outputs. completed, took 1ms
[WARNING] isar_generator on test/widget_test.dart:
Your current `analyzer` version may not fully support your current SDK version.

Analyzer language version: 3.1.0
SDK language version: 3.4.0

Please update to the latest `analyzer` version (6.8.0) by running
`flutter packages upgrade`.

If you are not getting the latest version by running the above command, you
can try adding a constraint like the following to your pubspec to start
diagnosing why you can't get the latest version:

dev_dependencies:
  analyzer: ^6.8.0

[INFO] Generating SDK summary completed, took 8.4s
[INFO] Running build completed, took 10.2s
[INFO] Caching finalized dependency graph completed, took 211ms
[INFO] Succeeded after 10.4s with 6 outputs (33 actions)

When I tried to run the code, I encountered the following error:
lib/models/note.g.dart:18:7: Error: The integer literal 6284318083599466921 can't be represented exactly in JavaScript.
Try changing the literal to something that can be represented in JavaScript. In JavaScript 6284318083599466496 is the nearest value that can be represented exactly.
  id: 6284318083599466921,
      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
Failed to compile application.

Questions

What is causing this issue with the integer literal not being represented exactly in JavaScript?
How can I modify my setup or code to avoid this error and get ISAR running correctly?


MAX_SAFE_INTEGER  If you need integers bigger than that either use BigInt or if you only use them as IDs but don't want to do calculations on them, string

This question is similar to: What is JavaScript's highest integer value that a number can go to without losing precision?. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Thank you, but it happened when I first time compiled the code and the DB is empty. Therefore, I am little confused.

If it's a compilation error, what does lib/models/note.g.dart say around line 18?

@derpirscher This question is about Flutter (being compiled to JavaScript). While the question you linked is relevant, it's definitely not a duplicate.

It appears only V4 has web support but on their github side it is written ISAR V4 IS NOT READY FOR PRODUCTION USE.  There seems to be a fork. Has anyone try it?
